# Zendframework - Adding an action to existing controller results in permission denied

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using Zendframework (2.3), I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong when attempting to create a new action and view on an existing controller. I've read some relevant [documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) but still fail to see what I'm missing.

Currently the controller basically defaults to a single action (main), I would like to add an additional one.

EG:

`/list-item/main` => // Existing Route
`/list-item/add`  => // New Route I would like to add.

This is how my `module.config.php` looks:

```
return array(

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'list-item' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/list-item[/:action][/:id][/:id1][/:id2][/:id3][/:id4][/:id5]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'ListItem',
                        'action' => 'main',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'ListItem' => 'ListItem\Controller\ListItemController',
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

If I can read this configuration correctly, the actual action name is optional, but the module will default to the main action. Yet it is flexible to allow for any action to be attempted.

So, I proceeded to add a new public function into the ListItemController, assumed this is how the convention works:

```
public function addAction() {
  return new ViewModel();
}
```

And with it a new view file into the module's views folder, in fact right next to `main.phtml` but called `add.phtml`.

But when I attempt to access the route `/list-item/add` I only get a `permission denied`. Funny, because the actual status is 200. But I have no other information. I honestly don't even know if this is a ZF thing, I can only assume.

Also, I'm using `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/` in case the web server might have something to do.

Thanks in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to find detailed error in log files

Comment: @bxN5 I'm running the app with the local php server. The only logs I have are access logs, that are coming on the terminal. And the request is returning with status 200, no errors printed. Are there any other logs I could look for in the system or the project directory?

Comment: error log for example if it's apache

Comment: I'm running the app using php's built in web server. I've checked the php.ini and set the [error_log](https://php.net/error-log) varibale, but didn't get anything on the log file. Thanks anyways, though.